# What is easiest way to deploy using docker-compose.yml on GCP in 2018?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

Time is changing and it's too fast in Cloud environment.
I'm developing my project with docker-compose and want to deploy it on GCP using docker-compose.yml and want to know how to deploy it with docker-compose at the easiest way.
Because there seems many ways on GCP in this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use Kompose to deploy docker-compose.yml in kubernetes (GCP or openshift [here](http://kompose.io/))

kompose can convert docker-compose file into deploy, services files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Kompose is a great option to migrate to K8s. You may also want to use Google Container Builder as well if you don't want to use an entire cluster. [Here is an article](https://medium.com/@kevinsimper/building-docker-images-with-docker-compose-on-google-cloud-container-builder-292b1eb3fd31) that addresses this solution.

Comment: For clarification this approach is for running docker-compose during the build process, ex. for running tests on it. But not for deploying for a long running service.